# Filter Azure Table Storage by RowKey and StartsWith using the Python SDK

Tags: c#, python, rest, azure, azure-table-storage

I have seen that Azure Table Storage supports querying records by a partial `RowKey` (in addition to the `PartitionKey`) (C# example [here](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/azure-table-storage-using-startswith-to-filter-on-rowkeys/)).

However, I can't find anything related to this in the actual docs on filtering query results ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd894031.aspx)).

I am trying to using the **Python Azure-Storage SDK** to query a subset of `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` combinations where the `RowKey` starts with a certain string. I have the code (which works, but does not do correct filtering any row keys):

```
from azure.storage.table import TableService
table_service = TableService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY)
entities = table_service.query_entities('mystoragetable', filter='PartitionKey eq mypartitionkey"', num_results=10)
```

However, I can't figure out the syntax for also adding a partial (`startswith`) constraint to the filter.

**Has anyone had any experience with filtering Azure Table Storage queries by partial `RowKey` strings?** I am at a loss here; however, it seems to be possible via the `C#` code in the example above.

If there are any extra docs about how to do this via a REST call, I can probably translate that into the Python usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your RowKey values contains words and you only want to filter the words starting with `a` and `b`, this is what you would add to your query:

```
(RowKey ge 'a' and RowKey lt 'c') ==> (RowKey >= 'a' && RowKey < 'c')
```

So your code would be something like:

```
entities = table_service.query_entities('mystoragetable', filter="PartitionKey eq 'mypartitionkey' and RowKey ge '<starts with substring>'", num_results=10)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I wasn't grasping the concept that `ge` and `le` could apply to characters also, but I suppose that makes perfect sense. Thanks!